# There is no GAC folder on my clients PC

Tags: .net-4.5, clickonce, gac

I've created an installer for my vb.net application and given it to a client to install, but it's getting a series of errors. I appear to have fixed most of them, but the one that's really causing an issue is one saying

> Unable to install or run the application. The application requires that assembly CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.XmlSerialize Version 12.0.1100.0 to be installed in the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) first.

However, there is no GAC folder on the clients PC when looking in Windows\assembly

I've even searched the Local Disk for GAC, and the only folder results are GAC_MSIL, GAC_32 and GAC_64...

Where do I put this file to make the application work? Why is there not a GAC folder in the Windows\Assembly root?

Comment: .NET isn't installed then.

Comment: @rory.ap I installed 4.5.1 framework if this is what you mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The GAC folder for .NET 4.5 (and anything after 4.0) is here:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly
```

There are three folders beneath that (as you've found):

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_32
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_64
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly\GAC_MSIL
```

Where the assemblies should reside depend on which type of CPU(x86 or x64) they target.  You shouldn't put assemblies in those folders yourself; they should be installed there by your deployment mechanism.

Comment: Hi Rory, thanks for this information, how would I go about making the deployment mechanism install the assemblies? I've never done an installer/deployment system before, as this is my first application that's needed one, hence why I'm so lacking in knowledge!

Comment: You tagged the question with ClickOnce.  I don't know anything about that (I use InstallShield LE).  The use of the deployment technologies is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: Okay, thanks, I'll look at using InstallShield, there seem to be plenty of articles and tutorials out there that will help me... Will this also package the databases and Crystal Reports runtimes with it? Or at least provide the option to install those too?

Comment: You can install dependencies, yes.  What do you mean by "databases"?  It won't create databases for you in your DBMS unless you create a custom action (i.e. script) that runs as part of the installation.  You might need the non-free (i.e. not "LE" -- "Limited Edition") version of InstallShield to get it to run your custom action at the desired point in the installation.

Comment: Well, I currently use a .ini file to store the database location, so ideally I'd like the installer to create the database/copy the one that I already am using to test the system, and put it by default in the program folder that will be created with all the files in. Then I can use a writeIni function to set the database location in the .ini

Comment: You can do that, but it's a learning curve with LE depending on your skill level.

Comment: Thanks, Rory, this was really helpful!